# Does repo's Nvidia disable Nouveau

Tags: fedora, drivers, rpm, nvidia, nouveau

Yes, it has many Q&A about the Nouveau x Nvidia drivers concerning Fedora 24.

However, I didn't find one detail I need to know.

I entered the [guide](http://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia) to look for,

> As nouveau is enabled by default starting with Fedora 11, you may experience problem which is caused by the nouveau kernel module being present in the initrd image. After the reboot, this command should not output anything: lsmod |grep nouveau

*SO MY DOUBT IS*

If I do install Nvidia driver from repository (RPM Fusion) as said, so will I get the Nouveau driver disabled automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the Nouveau should be disabled manually before of installing another video driver. So I did it and I've got trouble to use the GT520's under Fedora 24.

My results:

- the repository's one has a problem with the secondary video;
- the downloaded driver has a problem of shutting the desktop later.

The Nouveau came back then. It is flawless. Even although the Nvidia may have more performance than that.